# Probability of $A^c \cap B$

Tags: probability

If event $A$ is a subset of $B$ and $3P(A)=P(B) =3/4$, find $P(A^c \cap B)$

The answer (I think) is $P(\text{Only $B$, no overlap with $A$}) = P(B) - P(A \cap B)$. Now $P(B) = \cfrac {3}{4}$ and $P(A)= \cfrac{1}{4}$, but how do I find $P(A\cap B)?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A\subset B$, we obtain: $$P(A\cap B)=P(A).$$
Id est, $$P(A^c\cap B)=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

If $A \subset B$ then $P(A \cap B)=P(A)$

Thus

$$P(\overline{A}\cap B)=P(B)-P(A)=\frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$A\subset B$  so $A\cap B=A.$